# Navigating between Multiple pages in Xamarin.forms?

Tags: android, navigation, xamarin.forms

I have a content view and left navigation drawer which are commons on 4 pages and Content view contains 4 icons which navigates between 4 different pages. I want to keep my content view and left navigation drawer on all 4 pages.
I create a Master details page and set Master page to Left navigation Drawer and i am changing the details page each time.
I got the exception as android can navigate only page at a time while navigating between multiple pages.
Following is my Rootpage and ContentView Page

```
 public class RootPage : MasterDetailPage
    {
        LeftNavigationPanel menuPage;
        public RootPage(string detailSel)
        {
            menuPage = new LeftNavigationPanel(); //This is the left navigation class. rename later.
            Master = menuPage;
            if (detailSel.Equals(""))
            {

                var detail = new NavigationPage(new Tabpage());
                Detail = detail; //homepage
                detail.Icon = "leftnav.png";
                App.navigation = detail.Navigation;
            }
            else if (detailSel.Equals("1"))
            {

                var detail = new NavigationPage(new Post());
                Detail = detail; //homepage
               detail.Icon = "leftnav.png";
               App.navigation = detail.Navigation;
             //  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("page1: " + Navigation.NavigationStack[Navigation.NavigationStack.Count-1]);

            }
            else if (detailSel.Equals("2"))
            {
                var detail = new NavigationPage(new TrackTabPage());
                Detail = detail; //homepage
                detail.Icon = "leftnav.png";
                App.navigation = detail.Navigation;
               // System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("page1: " + Navigation.NavigationStack[Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 1]);

            }
            }
    }
```

ContentView

```
public partial class HomeContentView : ContentView
    {
        public HomeContentView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private async void read_click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!((Navigation.NavigationStack[Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 1]) is Tabpage))
            {

                //await Navigation.PopAsync();
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new RootPage(""));
                // this.Navigation.PopAsync();
            }
        }
        private async void post_click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!((Navigation.NavigationStack[Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 1]) is Post))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("page: "+ Navigation.NavigationStack[Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 1]);
              //  await Navigation.PopAsync();
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new RootPage("1"));


            }
        }
        private async void track_click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!((Navigation.NavigationStack[Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 1]) is TrackTabPage))
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("page: " + Navigation.NavigationStack[Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 1]);
              //  await Navigation.PopAsync();
                await Navigation.PushAsync(new RootPage("2"));
            }
        }
        private void play_click(Object sender, EventArgs e) { }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `Navigation` from the Detail-Page, because you set the Detail as a `new NavigationPage()`.

I usually use following code to geht the `INavigation` to navigate inside my app:

```
public static INavigation GetNavigation()
{
    var mdp = Application.Current.MainPage as MasterDetailPage;
    if (mdp != null)
    {
        // Return the navigation of the detail-page
        return mdp.Detail.Navigation;
    }

    var np = Application.Current.MainPage as NavigationPage;
    if (np != null)
    {
        // Page is no MasterDetail-Page, but has a navigation
        return np.Navigation;
    }

    // No navigation found (just set the page, instead of navigation)
    return null;
}
```

And use it like the following example:

```
var nav = GetNavigation();
if(nav != null)
{
    await nav.PushAsync(new Tabpage());
}
else
{
    // Just set the page, because there is no navigation
    Application.Current.MainPage = new new Tabpage();

    // Or like this
    Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new Tabpage());
}
```

**Update**

I changed my answer a little bit (thanks for the comment, I just don't realized this). Do not use `new Rootpage("")` to change the page. With that you create a new Navigation on top of the current Navigation.. that makes no sense.

Just `Push` your page onto the current navigation you get by `GetNavigation()`.

Please read the [documentation about the navigation pattern](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/navigation/) in Xamarin.Forms for further informations.

Comment: What should i write in root page constructor?? can i keep it as it is?

Comment: It depends on how you want to navigate inside your app. In the "normal" case, you have one `NavigationPage` in which you push new pages. With that, the user can navigate back. I updated my answer

Comment: in my app..there are 4 icons on each main 4 pages constantly placed which take care of navigation between 4 main page...and functionality is like..you can go to any page from any current page by clicking on respective icon..there is no one decided flow..how can i do such navigations